# mysql filtering same name with multiple records(different states)

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table where I can store the same name with different states.

```
|ID|name|state
  1  A    1
  2  A    2
  3  B    3
  4  C    1
```

There 3 states 1,2,3.

How can I find those records which has no state 3, maximum 2?

In this example A and C has no state 3 so they would be the result of the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `records` WHERE (`state_id`!=3)
```

It only returns rows without state 3 but it can be that value.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `records` WHERE (`state_id`!=3) GROUP BY name..use

Comment: Sorry, what exactly would the desired result look like? Edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35dbe/2

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM `records` r 
LEFT JOIN `records` r3
ON r.name = r3.name
  AND r3.state=3
WHERE r3.state IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a DISTINCT and NOT IN?

Something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
  FROM Table1 t 
  WHERE Name NOT IN (
    SELECT Name 
    FROM Table1 s 
    WHERE s.State = 3)
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cef99/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select name from t 
group by name
having sum(case when state = 3 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8bb5/2